# Mass Wall Post to multiple users?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a contest App. And many users have installed the app. I have stored the offline_access tokens of these users. I want to send a message to all users of app at the end of contest. What is the best way to do it. Because when I do it in a while loop the page never loads and browser just shows loading animation gif on tab.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need the user access tokens to accomplish something similar to what you're trying to do.

First off, mass-wall posting is both a violation of the [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies) (specifically IV.2, IV.3), but it's also really spammy and users will react negatively, probably blocking your app and ultimately it may get banned from Facebook. So don't do that.

Instead, you should utilise the intended social channel for notifying users of new content, [App to user Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#app_to_user).

This is pretty simple to do, as per the [Graph API docs for apprequests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests) you just make the following API call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/apprequests?app_access_token=APPTOKEN`

Where USERID is each user's Facebook ID and APPTOKEN is always your applications unique access token (see the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) if you do not know how to obtain one of those). You will also need to include parameters such as `message`, which you can read more about in the docs.